# How to prepare a headless machine?

Tags: gentoo, sshd, headless, rc, funtoo

I'm currently preparing an SD-card for my Raspberry Pi, i.e. an ARM machine, while I'm sitting on a x86 one. Therefore I cannot simply `chroot` into it and run `rc-update add sshd default`. So, how else can I set this up without having to connect the device itself?

Answer (score 2):

As http://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo_Linux_Installation_on_ARM explains, it is sufficient to do a

```
ln -sf /etc/init.d/sshd /mnt/SDcard/etc/runlevels/default
ln -sf /etc/init.d/dhcpcd /mnt/SDcard/etc/runlevels/default
```

(adding `dhcpcd` is optional though you have to setup *some* networking)

`rc-update` basically does this after checking that a service's dependencies are met, which in the case of `sshd` are none. However, remember to setup a root password (e.g. by pasting `openssl passwd -1`'s output into `etc/shadow`'s `root:YOUR_PASSWORD_MD5:14698:0:::::`) or public key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your host system to run ARM binaries using the QEMU emulator. This is done by registering an userspace-application for a specific executable format to the kernel's binfmt-functionality.

Since the setup-procedure is quite lengthy, let me just post some links to howtos:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Crossdev_qemu-static-user-chroot
http://linux-sunxi.org/Gentoo
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-996114.html
https://wwwold.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/embedded/handbook/?part=1&chap=5